# FICA taxes withheld on F1 visa, employer said to give correct W2C moving withheld FICA to Federal? (Unique Case)

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, withholding, f1-student-visa

I was an intern at a company in 2016. I am currently on F1 visa (Non Resident Alien under 5 years) and therefore exempt fro SSN and Medicare taxes (FICA).

My employer withheld these taxes and gave me a W2 in January 2017.

They said they cannot issue a refund to me, nor give me a letter for Form 843.
However they can give a corrected W2C moving all FICA taxes to Federal taxes.

Does this mean if I file my tax returns with new W2C then I will get my refund of FICA as it will count as excess Federal withheld?

---

There have been questions like these in the past but none of them addressed what happens if employer moves FICA to Federal.

Comment: Can an employer even do that? Doesn't the employer have to report amounts withheld quarterly to the government, where they report withheld income tax and withheld FICA taxes separately?

Comment: @user102008 Well they have mentioned that they will do it. I am not sure why cant they do it? Also I interned last quarter of 2016 so maybe they can. Do you know the answer to the question?